# Create view for multiple language dependent tables, but just one column for language

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one central table that contains all dates for a few years (primary key) and then the week, weekday, month, quarter and fiscal periods etc (simplyfied in coding below).

I have 2 additional tables, that contain the descriptions for e.g. the weekday and the month. These 2 tables are language dependend, which means I have a primary key, which contains the field "language" and is either "EN" or "DE" (english, german, french etc).

I like to create a view on that, but with only one single field "language"-column and if I query that view with [where language is "EN"], then I like the view to take only the records in english. At this moment I have to use 2 times the language with different aliases, but that seems odd to me (and I have much more of those text tables).

This is my central table for dates:

```
CREATE TABLE test.`/dwh/calendar/date_dir` (
  date date NOT NULL,
  mn decimal(2, 0) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL DEFAULT 00 COMMENT 'Month',
  wkday decimal(1, 0) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'Day of the week',
  PRIMARY KEY (date)
   )
ENGINE = INNODB,
AVG_ROW_LENGTH = 16384,
CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci,
COMMENT = 'Directory of dates and corresponding objects';
```

This table contains the descriptions of each month:

```
CREATE TABLE test.`/dwh/calendar/mn_descr` (
  mn decimal(2, 0) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL COMMENT 'Month',
  language char(2) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Language key',
  descr_short char(20) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Short description',
  PRIMARY KEY (mn, language)
)
ENGINE = INNODB,
AVG_ROW_LENGTH = 2730,
CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci,
COMMENT = 'Names of month';
```

This one the names of weekdays:

```
CREATE TABLE test.`/dwh/calendar/wkday_descr` (
  wkday decimal(1, 0) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL COMMENT 'Day of the week',
  language char(2) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Language key',
  descr_short char(20) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Short description',
  PRIMARY KEY (wkday, language)
)
ENGINE = INNODB,
AVG_ROW_LENGTH = 2730,
CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci,
COMMENT = 'Names of weekdays';
```

And this is my current ugly view:

```
SELECT
  `/dwh/calendar/date_dir`.`date` AS `date`,
  `/dwh/calendar/date_dir`.`mn` AS `mn`,
  `/dwh/calendar/date_dir`.`wkday` AS `wkday`,
  `/dwh/calendar/yrmn_descr`.`language` AS `yrmn_language`,
  `/dwh/calendar/yrmn_descr`.`descr_short` AS `yrmn_descr_short`,
  `/dwh/calendar/mn_descr`.`descr_short` AS `mn_descr_short`,
  `/dwh/calendar/wkday_descr`.`descr_short` AS `wkday_descr_short`,
  `/dwh/calendar/mn_descr`.`language` AS `mn_language`,
  `/dwh/calendar/wkday_descr`.`language` AS `wkday_language`
FROM (((`/dwh/calendar/date_dir`
  JOIN `/dwh/calendar/wkday_descr`
    ON (`/dwh/calendar/date_dir`.`wkday` = `/dwh/calendar/wkday_descr`.`wkday`))
  JOIN `/dwh/calendar/mn_descr`
    ON (`/dwh/calendar/date_dir`.`mn` = `/dwh/calendar/mn_descr`.`mn`))
```

So, the view works, but is ugly and does not seem right. It should have only one language column and what ever I pass to that should be moved down to the text tables automatically. I cant ask the users to enter the language 5 times or write a whole bunch of python to feed those fields. Does not seem right...

Comment: By the backticks and the InnoDB engine is assume this is for MySQL. I added that tag. Should this be wrong please change it, so that it indicates the DBMS you're using.

Comment: This appears like a database design issue as same columns appear. Normalization suggests maintaining one language table with time period indicator column.

Comment: No, its not a design issue. The main table contains the dates (language independent) and the others contain the name of weekday and name of month, both language dependent. Putting that into one language table would not be normalization. It would be mixing things that dont belong to each other. We would also not put customer and vendors in a single table. The "same column" is the language key.

Answer (score 0):

Include the language in the second join's predicate, so that it's checked whether the language of the month is the same as that of the weekday.

```
SELECT `/dwh/calendar/date_dir`.`date` `date`,
       `/dwh/calendar/date_dir`.`mn` `mn`,
       `/dwh/calendar/date_dir`.`wkday` `wkday`,
       `/dwh/calendar/yrmn_descr`.`language` `yrmn_language`,
       `/dwh/calendar/yrmn_descr`.`descr_short` `yrmn_descr_short`,
       `/dwh/calendar/mn_descr`.`descr_short` `mn_descr_short`,
       `/dwh/calendar/wkday_descr`.`descr_short` `wkday_descr_short`,
       `/dwh/calendar/mn_descr`.`language` `language`
       FROM `/dwh/calendar/date_dir`
            INNER JOIN `/dwh/calendar/wkday_descr`
                       ON `/dwh/calendar/wkday_descr`.`wkday` = `/dwh/calendar/date_dir`.`wkday`
            INNER JOIN `/dwh/calendar/mn_descr`
                       ON `/dwh/calendar/mn_descr`.`mn` = `/dwh/calendar/date_dir`.`mn`
                          AND `/dwh/calendar/mn_descr`.`language` = `/dwh/calendar/wkday_descr`.`language`;
```

Comment: Thanks, sticky bit. Thats a nice and easy approach! And thanks for the other tag.